# Determine How Long For Graph To Be Completely Visited

Tags: python, algorithm, graph-theory

> Suppose there is a population of 500 people, and each person knows
> exactly 4 other people in the population. Suppose one person gets
> infected with a disease, and that disease is guaranteed to infect the
> other 4 people that person knows in exactly 1 day's time.
>
> Write an algorithm to determine how many days it takes for everybody
> to be infected, given an input adjacency matrix.

I can't figure out how to properly keep track of the days. I tried the following, but it just gives me a number close to the total number of nodes (it should be much lower):

```
import random
random.seed(20)

nodes = 500
num_connections = 4

# generate random graph
graph = []
for node_num in range(nodes):
  myrow = [0 for node in range(nodes - num_connections)] + [1 for connection in range(num_connections)]
  random.shuffle(myrow)
  graph.append(myrow)


days = 0
visited = [0]
queue = [0]
while queue:
  ss = queue.pop(0)
  for neighbor, is_connected in enumerate(graph[ss]):
    if is_connected == 1 and neighbor not in visited:
      visited.append(neighbor)
      queue.append(neighbor)
      days += 1

print(days)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You can queue a tuple consisting of the `neighbor` and the day number. That way the last item read from the queue tells you the number of days it took. Or you can change the way the `visited` list works. When node `i` is visited, set `visited[i]` to the day number. Then you know the day for every node, and `max(visited)` is the number of days it took to finish.

Comment: There is no reason that your "queue" has to be just "person".  Your queue could instead consist of (person, day-on-which-they-get-sick).

Answer (score 1):

1. find longest shortest path from first infected person to any other person,
   using the Dijkstra algorithm.
2. The length of this path is the number
   of days.

Answer (score 0):

your problem is equivalent to finding the longest shortest route in the graph. but if you want to fix your current code, I fixed it for you :)

```
import random

random.seed(20)

nodes = 50
num_connections = 4

# generate random graph
graph = []
for node_num in range(nodes):
    myrow = [0 for node in range(nodes - num_connections)] + [1 for connection in range(num_connections)]
    random.shuffle(myrow)
    graph.append(myrow)

days = 0
visited = [0]
queue = [0]
while len(visited) < nodes:
    patients = queue.copy()
    queue.clear()
    days += 1
    while len(patients) > 0:
        ss = patients.pop(0)
        for neighbor, is_connected in enumerate(graph[ss]):
            if is_connected == 1 and neighbor not in visited:
                visited.append(neighbor)
                queue.append(neighbor)
    if len(queue) == 0:
        print(f'The given directional graph is not connected, after {days} days, {len(visited)} persons has been infected')
        exit()

print(days)
```